# Error deleting files with FineUploader when using more than one uploader in the same jsp

Tags: file-io, fine-uploader

I am uploading several files with FineUploader and I have a cancel button to stop the upload process and delete all the files that have been uploaded.

**Server code:**

```
public void doDelete(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    String uuid = req.getPathInfo().replaceAll("/", "");
    FileUtils.deleteUploadedFile(uuid);
    resp.setStatus(successResponseCode);
}
```

**FineUploader definition**

```
myUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: $('#file-uploader')[0],
    multiple: false,
    autoUpload: true,
    deleteFile: {enabled: true, forceConfirm: false, endpoint: '/upload-portlet/fineupload/receiver'},
...
});

imageUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: $('#image-uploader')[0],
    multiple: false,
    autoUpload: true,
    deleteFile: {enabled: true, forceConfirm: false, endpoint: '/upload-portlet/fineupload/receiver'},
...
});
```

**clearFiles method**

```
function clearFiles() {
    if (myUploader && myUploader.getUploads()) {
        var array = myUploader.getUploads();
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            myUploader.deleteFile(array[i].id);
        }
    }
    if (imageUploader && imageUploader.getUploads()) {
        var array = imageUploader.getUploads();
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            imageUploader .deleteFile(array[i].id);
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't works for imageUploader but it does for myUploader. I get an error for imageUploader: " Object has no method 'getUploads' ".

If I modify the clearFiles method by

```
function clearFiles() {
    if (myUploader && myUploader.getUploads()) {
        var array = myUploader.getUploads();
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            myUploader.deleteFile(array[i].id);
        }
    }
    var array = document.getElementsByClassName("qq-upload-delete");
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i].style="display: inline;";
        array[i].click();
    }
}
```

It works. The templates for imageUploader and myUploader are the same ones.

Any idea why I could have the " Object has no method 'getUploads' " error?

Comment: Do you have a live example of this issue?

Comment: No, I am sorry. Both uploaders are similar but they also have some differences, for example callbacks or validation, but I was not able to find something that could be the reason. Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: The code _looks_ correct, so a live site or jsfiddle where this issue can be reproduced is required.  Without that, I'm not sure anyone will be able to offer any further assistance.  There is likely some issue in your code that is not visible in the fragments you have posted here.

Comment: Thanks Ray. I will try to debug the problem and if I don't get anything will create a jsfiddle.

Comment: The "Object has no method `getUploads`" would be thrown if the `imageUploader` object was, at the moment that `getUploads` is called on it, not actually an instance of Fine Uploader. Ensure you aren't declaring it a global variable, and/or assigning it to something else in another portion of your code. A `console.log(imageUploader)` just before your `if` statement in `clearFiles` might give you some insights.

Comment: Any news on this @Asier?

Comment: No, unfortunately I am not going to be able to work on this for a while. I will update as soon as possible.